# Looking to create a google sitemap with more than 500 pages

Tags: xml, sitemap

Can anyone point me to best sites to get this done ?

From what I understand is that if your site is over 500 pages, you need to pay ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where this limitation you're talking about is coming from, but you're probably looking for [Sitemap Indexes](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php#index).

They allow you to specify a set of sitemaps to be used instead of one huge file.

According to this page, each Sitemap file is limited to 50,000 URLs and must be no larger than 10MB.

Therefore I think you'll have a hard time reaching those limits, since you can index up to 50,000 sitemap files in a single file, which gives a maximum of 2,500,000,000 urls for one index.

And the best thing is you can have more than one Sitemap index file.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this one: http://gsitecrawler.com/

Answer (score 0):

Most XML sitemap generation sitemap websites I know have that limit however one that I found with a much higher limit is http://create-site-map.com - you can try that.